# server-side problemt: PHP Push message to Blackberry

Tags: php, blackberry, push-notification

I am using the client side code from http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Simplified-BIS-Push-client-sample/ta-p/693857 on the BlackBerry Developer Support forums.

I am able to get a registration response from the BlackBerry push server, however I am unable to get any push messages from the BlackBerry push server. The server side code is built in PHP. When I click on the button send, I obtain this error

```
---------------error---------------------------------------------
    An XML parser error has occured
    Invalid document end
    Response
---------------PHP code------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?php
    if ($_POST) {
        // APP ID provided by RIM
        $appid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
        // Password provided by RIM
        $password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        //Deliver before timestamp
        $deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+5 minutes'));

        //An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
        $addresstosendto[] = 'push_all';

        $addresses = '';
        foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
            $addresses .= '<address address-value="' . $value . '"/>';
        }

        // create a new cURL resource
        $err = false;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $messageid = microtime(true);

        $data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
        'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
        '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd">
        <pap>
        <push-message push-id="' . $messageid . '" deliver-before-timestamp="' . $deliverbefore . '" source-reference="' . $appid . '">'
        . $addresses .
        '<quality-of-service delivery-method="unconfirmed"/>
        </push-message>
        </pap>' . "\r\n" .
        '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
        'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
        stripslashes($_POST['message']) . "\r\n" .
        '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));

        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);

        //Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
        $p = xml_parser_create();
        xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
        $errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
        if ($errorcode > 0) {
            $err = true;
        }
        xml_parser_free($p);

        echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "<br \>\n";
        if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
            echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "<br \>\n";
            echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "<br \>\n";
            echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
            echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \> \n";
        } elseif ($err) {
            echo '<p>An XML parser error has occured</p>' . "\n";
            echo '<pre>' . xml_error_string($errorcode) ."</pre>\n";
            echo '<p>Response</p>' . "\n";
            echo '<pre>' . $xmldata . '</pre>' . "\n"
        } else {
            echo '<p>An error has occured</p>' . "\n";
            echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
            echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \>\n";
        }
    } else {
        showhtml();
    }

    function showhtml() {
        ?>
    <html>
    <head><title>Blackberry PUSH Bishes!!!</title></head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <p>Message to push:</p>
    <textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea>
    <p></p><input type="submit" value="Push Data"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Just a note to future solvers, the `"\n\r"` line doesn't appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to push messages to my BlackBerry by adding the following line before **curl_exec**.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    // APP ID provided by RIM

    $appid = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    // Password provided by RIM
    $password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    //Deliver before timestamp
    $deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+5 minutes'));

    //An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
    $addresstosendto[] = 'push_all';

    $addresses = '';
    foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
        $addresses .= '<address address-value="' . $value . '"/>';
    }

    // create a new cURL resource
    $err = false;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $messageid = microtime(true);

    $data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd">
    <pap>
    <push-message push-id="' . $messageid . '" deliver-before-timestamp="' . $deliverbefore . '" source-reference="' . $appid . '">'
    . $addresses .
    '<quality-of-service delivery-method="unconfirmed"/>
    </push-message>
    </pap>' . "\r\n" .
    '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
    'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
    stripslashes($_POST['message']) . "\r\n" .
    '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    //Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
    $p = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
    $errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
    if ($errorcode > 0) {
        $err = true;
    }
    xml_parser_free($p);

    echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "<br \>\n";
    if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
        echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "<br \>\n";
        echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "<br \>\n";
        echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
        echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \> \n";
    } elseif ($err) {
        echo '<p>An XML parser error has occured</p>' . "\n";
        echo '<pre>' . xml_error_string($errorcode) ."</pre>\n";
        echo '<p>Response</p>' . "\n";
        echo '<pre>' . $xmldata . '</pre>' . "\n";
    } else {
        echo '<p>An error has occured</p>' . "\n";
        echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
        echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \>\n";
    }
} else {
    showhtml();
}

function showhtml() {
    ?>
<html>
<head><title>Blackberry PUSH Bishes!!!</title></head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<p>Message to push:</p>
<textarea name="message" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea>
<p></p><input type="submit" value="Push Data"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I didn't get the same error. But I didn't receive any notification in my device. I obtain this answer when I run the code Our PUSH-ID: xxxxxxxxxxx
PUSH-ID: xxxxxxxxxx
REPLY-TIME: 2011-12-20T07:32:28Z
Response CODE: 1001
Response DESC: The request has been accepted for processing.

Comment: Was your Sample Push Enabled Application running at that time?

Comment: No I obtain an exception when I register "Request to register failed. Caused by java.io.IOExcetion:Network operation [Subscribe] failed. Make sure that Content Provider URL is accessible"

Comment: is BIS activated on your phone and is the ip address of your php server publicly accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 <?php
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// APP ID provided by RIM
$appid = '';
// Password provided by RIM
$password = '';

//Deliver before timestamp
$deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+15 minutes'));

//An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
$addresstosendto[] = 'push_all';

$addresses = '';
foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
$addresses .= '<address address-value="' . $value . '"/>';
}

// create a new cURL resource
$err = false;
$ch = curl_init();
$messageid = microtime(true);

$data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd">
<pap>
<push-message push-id="' . $messageid . '" deliver-before-timestamp="' . $deliverbefore . '" source-reference="' . $appid . '">'
. $addresses .
'<quality-of-service delivery-method="confirmed"/>
</push-message>
</pap>' . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
stripslashes('This is my message') . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

//Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
$errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
if ($errorcode > 0) {
echo xml_error_string($errorcode);
$err = true;
}
xml_parser_free($p);

echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "<br \>\n";
if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \> \n";
} else {
echo '<p>An error has occured</p>' . "\n";
echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \>\n";
}


?>
```